# C++ typename in function definition

Tags: c++, typename

This bit of code if from an example for a linked list but I'm struggling to understand the 2nd line of this function, could someone talk me through it?

```
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::Node* List<T>::search(T d)
{
    if(!head) return NULL;
    Node* cur = head;
    while(cur) {
        if(cur->data == d) return cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: It's the use of two scope operators that I don't understand

Comment: This is where the example came from: http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/linkedlist.php#linkedlistexample10

Comment: @JamesGillard one is for return type and one for function name...

Comment: @JamesGillard That's not in your body *or* title.

Comment: Just a side note, its likely that it would be better to use `const T &d` as `search()` parameter.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz because the struct Node is declared inside the class List, should've noticed that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There will be a `*type* Node` somewhere in the `List<>` class template (or specialization) so when referring to that type the syntax `typename List<T>::Node` must be used.

[Dependant names](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) can be disambiguated with the `typename` keyword.

Comment: Why a typedef? Could be an enum, a struct or a class. Even a template alias. So you meant: there will be a nested typename in the `List<>` _specialization/instantiation_

Comment: You're right. I've had this problem with typedefs recently so I was a bit blinkered, thanks.

Comment: I added "or specialization" as this is really _the_ reason why the compiler really can't know all typenames at first pass (aside from CRTP, by the way). +1 for mentioning the relevant term "Dependent name" though

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the second line in the your post, that says "Search is a function that takes an argument of type `T` and returns a pointer to a type specific to the Linked List called `List<T>::Node`.

If you mean the second line in the function `search` itself, it is just initializing a local var `cur` to a member variable called `head` (here likely referring to the head of the linked list data st.). The rest of the code just iterates our the elements of the list until a node containing data that's being searched is found and returned.

Comment: Linked list data st.? I didn't know linked lists had their own patron saint these days.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `A<T>::X`. X could be a type (typedef, struct, etc) or it could be variable (static variable). When you are "inside" a template, and use a type which has a template in this fashion, you must help the compiler by adding `typename` if your X is a type.